# Typescript: narrowing types with destructuring

Tags: typescript, react-apollo

The following code errors:

```
type Foo = {
  a: true,
  b: null,
  c: null
} | {
  a: false,
  b: Error,
  c: null
} | {
  a: false,
  b: null,
  c: { prop: number}
}

function getFoo(): Foo {

  return { a: false, b: null, c: { prop: 5 } };

}

const { a, b, c } = getFoo();

if (!a && !b) {
  console.log(c.prop)
}
```

The error given is:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.(2531)
```

This makes somewhat sense, because when the result from `getFoo()` was destructured, the types from the larger `Foo` object was lost.

However, I'm trying to replicate what the Apollo React client is doing:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery('...');

if (loading) {
  return '..';
}
if (error) {
  return '..';
}
return data.foo;
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out from their source how they make this work.

Is this doable in Typescript at all? My best guess is that their types might not be 100% accurate, and they say they always return `data` even when they don't.

Comment: what Apollo type are you comparing it to? `QueryResult` has type ``` data: TData | undefined;
    error?: ApolloError;
    loading: boolean;
```

Comment: @DamianGreen, that looks like it would be it. I am curious how they avoid 'Object is possibly 'undefined' with all their examples

Comment: It is not possible to have type guard between 2 variables. You can make a link between variable a and b to tell that: if condition of a ==> b is something else. For Apollo React client, I think that strictNullChecks is disabled

Comment: @htn, make sense.. that's unfortunate! If you submit that as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have type guard between 2 variables. You can make a link between variable a and b to tell that: if a condition of a is met ==> b is something else. For Apollo React client, I think that strictNullChecks is disabled

Answer (score 0):

The example now works since TypeScript 4.6. However, you must use `const` to destructure.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html